# Convert multiple integer columns into a datetime value

Tags: sql-server

[image: Table Structure]

I have the above table and I want to create a DATETIME value from it.

I've tried a number of ways using CONCAT, CONVERT and CAST to glue these together in a way that produces a datetime value and can't get there. I can produce a string that will convert like this.

```
CONCAT(
    '''',
    Year, 
    '-', 
    CASE LEN(Month) WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('0', LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Month)))) ELSE CAST(Month AS VARCHAR(2)) END,
    '-', 
    CASE LEN(Day) WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('0', LTRIM(RTRIM(STR(Day)))) ELSE CAST(Day AS VARCHAR(2)) END,
    ' ', 
    Hour, 
    ':00:00.000',
    ''''
)
```

However, I wrap that output in a call to cast or convert it fails.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at `DATEFROMPARTS` or `DATETIMEFROMPARTS`.

Comment: What @Larnu said. However, this is only in newer versions of SQL, what version are you using?

Comment: SELECT CAST(
 CAST([Year] as varchar(4)) + '-' +
 CAST([Month] as varchar(2)) + '-' +
 CAST([Day] as varchar(2)) + ' ' +
 CAST([Hour] as varchar(2)) + ':00:00'
 as DateTime
)

FROM [Table_1]

Comment: I wouldn't say every supported version of SQL Server is "newer", @PhilipKelley . More like it's only not supported on very old versions.

Comment: I ended up using ```DATETIMEFROMPARTS```. Thanks @Larnu. I upvoted your comment, but can't credit you the answer.

Comment: You can always post your own answer, @ShawnTaylor . I just pointed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Select Cast(Convert(nvarchar,[year])+'-'+Convert(nvarchar,[month])+'-'+Convert(nvarchar,[day])+' '+Convert(nvarchar,[hour])+':00:00.00' as datetime) from [YOUR TABLE]